# Berry-Esseen Theorem with Continuity Correction

Tags: mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities, normal-approximation

Given independent but non-identical random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots ,X_n$ with $E[X_i]=0,$ $E[X_i^2]=\sigma_i^2=1$ and finite absolute third moments $\rho_i=E[|X_i|^3].$
Let $$S_n = {\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$$ with cdf $F_n.$ Then from the Berry_Esseen theorem we can bound the error in estimating $F_n$ with a normal approximation: $$\left|F_n(x) - \Phi \left( {{x} \over {\sqrt{n}}} \right) \right| \leq 0.56 \sum_{i=1}^n \rho_i,$$ where $\Phi(x)$ is the standard normal cdf. [The above is slightly modified from Wikipedia.]

Now suppose the $X_i$ are discrete, taking on integer values. In practice we would apply a continuity correction to the approximation, using $$F_n(x) \approx \Phi \left( { { {{x+{{1} \over {2}}}}  } \over {\sqrt{n}}} \right).$$

The continuity correction is intended to provide increased accuracy. Can this be quantified? That is, does there exist a Berry-Esseen inequality of the form $$\left| F_n(x) - \Phi \left( { { {{x+ {{1} \over {2}}}} } \over {\sqrt{n}}} \right) \right| \leq k \sum_{i=1}^n \rho_i \ \ ?$$

Comment: The continuity correction is _not_ applied in the way you have stated it. Reflect that $\Phi(x+\frac 12)$ can be quite a bit different from $\Phi(x)$, far too much to be a "continuity" correction.

Comment: I will try to restate.

Comment: I've edited the problem statement now.

Comment: I do not understand where this continuity correction comes from. Why is "$x+1/2$" to be preferred in the argument of $\Phi$ instead of "$x$"? I hope your answer will show clearly why "$x-1/2$" wouldn't work just as well.  Note that the latter would be the value you use if you negated all the data. But why would negating the data change the quality of the approximation?  After all, $-X$ has all the properties assumed of $X$, so what's good for $X$ ought to be good for $-X$!

Comment: We are trying to approximate the cdf of a discrete random variable with the cdf of a continuous one. So it makes sense to move or assign some probability that is within a neighborhood of the discrete domain point $x$ to $x.$ Try this: Look at the convolution of 3 IID discrete uniform random variables on $[-2,2].$ A normal cdf fit using $x$ as the argument has maximum absolute error of 0.0825 at $x=-1.$ Using $x-{{1} \over {2}}$ has max absolute error of 0.1569 at $x = 0.$ Using $x+{{1} \over {2}}$ has max absolute error of 0.0099 at both $x=-2$ and $x = 1.$

Answer (score 3):

Well, if $S_n$ is discrete, then we have $F_n(x)=F_n(x+\frac12)$ for $x\in \mathbb Z$, in which case we recover the same Berry-Esseen bound for the continuity correction as without:
$$\left| F_n(x)-\Phi\left(\frac{x+\frac12}{\sqrt n}\right)\right| = \left| F_n\left(x+\frac12\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{x+\frac12}{\sqrt n}\right)\right| \leq .56\sum_{i=1}^n \rho_i$$
Is this what you were looking for? Or were you wanting to show that the continuity correction allows for a strict improvement of the Berry-Esseen inequality?

Comment: I am looking for improvement, but it's nice to know there is no loss of accuracy - worth an upvote.